# Pack & unpack node_modules of an Electron Native application to be patched

Tags: node.js, npm, electron, node-modules, polyfills

First of all, I am generating an electron native application using *electron-builder*, *npm* and *npx*.
The next commands/steps are being executed to compile and generate the electron native application:

1. npm run build -- --prod --build-optimizer (to compile app)
2. npx electron-builder build --windows (to generate an electron windows app)

Later, I obtain a `myApp` folder which contains:

```
/win-unpacked
electron-builder-effective-config.yaml
myApp.exe
```

My application uses the `node_modules` folder which contains all node dependencies used in my application.

My question is: are there any way to unpack the native application or similar and patch new changes inside `node_modules`?

After perform an investigation, I have discovered that node dependencies are packed in system cache inside an `app.asar` file which contains a `dist` folder with some `.js` files.

**In developer tools:**

[image: devtools-dist-files]

**Inside `app.asar`:**

[image]

Are there any way to "deploy" node modules folder with the aim to perform patch operations of each package and change the code inside node modules folders?

I will appreciate any kind of help.

Answer (score 1):

Asar is a read only archiv format, so you cant patch any files in the archive.
But what you can do is to disable the asar option in your `build` config.

So in your `package.json` define it like this:

```
"build": {
    "appid": "........",
    "win":   {........},
    "asar":  false
}
```

if you build this, there is no asar archive anymore and you can overwrite any file...

what you can also do is using asar programatically. So you can unpack the asar archive, updating files and package new archive. See [here](https://github.com/electron/asar#using-programatically) how you can use it

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to what is being said here, patching a .asar archive is totally possible. I have published a library on NPM called [patch-asar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-asar) that does specifically this.

Comment: you cant patch asar files....what you did is unpack an asar file and creating a new one....thats not patching an asar file.